# Tell store to update without an actual data change

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I am trying to cleanup my React/Redux application's bootstrapping.

I create my redux story like this:

```
store = createStore(reducer, { ...initialState });
```

And on the next line I `subscribe`:

```
store.subscribe(() => ReactDOM.render(
  <App foo={store.getState().foo} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
));
```

When I start my application, the rendering of the `App` control is not occurring. I suppose this is because my `subscribe` is not firing since no data has changed yet.

I understand I could move the `subscribe` callback to a separate function and invoke it manually, but I was hoping to not have to create the separate function.

Is there a clean way to tell my `store` object to go ahead and fire it's `subscribe` callback without making an explicit data change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Store subscribers are called at the end of *every* call to `dispatch()`, regardless of whether the state was actually changed by the root reducer function.  So, you could in theory do `dispatch({type : "DUMMY_ACTION_NO_REDUCER_CARES_ABOUT"})`, and that will trigger the subscribers.

However, that's really pointless.  It's much simpler to do:

```
const renderApp =  () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App foo={store.getState().foo} />,
         document.getElementById('root')
    );
};

store.subscribe(renderApp);
renderApp();
```

Beyond that, unless you're just experimenting around with the bare basics of React and Redux and trying to learn how they work, you shouldn't actually be subscribing to the store manually.  Instead, you should use the official React-Redux library, which provides a `connect()` function that abstracts away the process of subscribing to the store for you.